# Elegant way of unpacking 1x1x3 uint8 into 1x3 uint8 in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

It appears weird to me that MATLAB returns me a `1x1x3` uint8 when I retrieve a RGB pixel in an image with `c = im(1, 1, :)`.

I need `1x3` uint8 instead. How may I unpack `1x1x3` uint8 into `1x3` uint8 *elegantly*?

Comment: The `squeeze` function does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change any array into a column vector with `:`. From there you can get a row vector using the transponse `'`.

```
c = c(:)';
```

If you have a list of `n` pixels in a `nx1x3` array, you can swap the 2nd and 3rd dimensions using `permute`.

```
pixel_list = permute(pixel_list,[1 3 2]);
```

MATLAB stores RGB images as a 3D array, with the colour values stored along the 3rd "depth" dimension. Accessing `c = im(1, 1, :)` returns exactly that: a 3-element vector that extends along the 3rd dimension.